# How to configure mosquitto's ACL without mosquitto_passwd when installed with snap?

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

At least on Ubuntu 18.04, mosquitto snap lacks mosquitto_passwd.

Comment: Build it yourself from the source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `sudo snap refresh`, then `mosquitto.passwd`, this has been added to the snap.